# Get name of array item in php

Tags: php, file, jpeg

I have an array in php, which contains .jpg files. How can I get the file-name if the first .jpg file?

I did the following (filesE is the array which contains all files starting with "edelweiss_" it's just .jpg files, which start with "edelweiss_"). Than I want to print the filename of the first file. It doesn't work. I'm lerning php.

```
$filesE = glob("edelweiss_*");

    if(!empty($filesE)){
        rsort($filesE);
        echo readdir($filesE[0]);
    }
```

Comment: You have the file names. what do you need readdir for? Does not make sense in this context.

Comment: [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/glob) returns you an array of file names.  After sorting the array, just `echo $filesE[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for.

```
$filesE = glob("edelweiss_*");
var_dump($filesE); echo '.<br>.';

echo($filesE[0]).'.<br>.';
```

In the golb you will probably put the path to the directory where the files are. If not in the current dir.